# Should i place Registered-Users Info in every table? to Restrict user access to his Own Data only

Tags: mysql, authentication

**Database:** Relational Database - MySQL

I am making a database with multiple tables. In order to see his data from tables, User will need to log in. **I only need to display those information(through web-pages) from the Table which only belongs to him**,  **so he wont get to access data of other users**.

**So, should i place Registered-Users Information in every table?**  just so when he wants to see data, i will "SELECT data from TABLE_ABC where (login_id = Id_of_current_user_log_ined )". I will put this condition in every query so he will only be able to access his/her own data and not someone else.

I made a Relational Schema but only 1 table inherits Login-Information from Login-Table while 3 of the tables don't have information on WHO does the data belong to?

Comment: @MichaelKutz Thanks , I am going to look into RLS now. Thanks for guiding me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

For table-level access restrictions:

```
GRANT SELECT ON tbl1 TO 'user'@'...';
GRANT SELECT ON tbl3 TO 'user'@'...';
```

Repeat as needed for each combination of user and table.

If you have a newer version of MySQL, see if "Roles" provides a simplification.

For row-level access restrictions, do not let the users query the tables.  Instead:

- Provide an app that they contact; it checks permissions before preforming (or not) the desired query.
- Use Stored Procedures.  See also the function `CURRENT_USER()`
- Use a `VIEW` -- then grant access to the view but not the table; have the view check whether the user is allowed to see the row.  See OP's comment.

Comment: Thanks for providing me more information, that makes things easier for me. I searched for row level security and got better understanding of what i am supposed to do.
What you said is exactly right. MySQL don't have Row Level Security feature, so i will place an Additional Column "OwnerOfData" in each table. Then i will make VIEW for the table " CREATE VIEW Books_Restricted as (SELECT * from Books where ( Books.OwnerOfData = CURRENT_USER() )". After that i will GRANT the Users access to the Books_Restricted ONLY.

The user won't be able to access data of others then. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @SayedMuhammadTalha - Ah, yes, a `VIEW` is also a good way to do it; maybe the 'best'.